# Creating Slide-In Text

Tags: c#, unity, lerp

I want to make my text slide like so:

[image: GIF]

This is from the game "Crossy Road". The movement is normally smoother that in the .GIF

Here are some more frames from the GIF to make you understand what I mean:

I'm sorry for the bad formatting, I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.

The text and the orange background seem to "expand" while moving smoothly to the right.

Comment: Ok, 1) your `actualSpeed` value is always going to be the same (you set it to `startSpeed` every frame and then subtract a little bit). 2) why is `prop` a variable? 3) [`.SmoothDamp()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html)

Comment: bonus props to @Draco18s for pointing out SmoothDamp

Comment: @Draco18s Excellent! You solved half the problem simply & efficiently! Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Draco18s You solved the entire problem! Thank you again! I appreciate efficient code.